# How do I fix TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, typeerror, calculator, addition

I'm coding a calculator and when I ran the program this Error message appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sergioley-languren/Documents/itt/independent_projects/Mathematical_Calculator.py", line 66, in <module>
    print(x + "+" + y + "=" + mathResult + ".") ; sleep(float(speed))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

This here is the code where the error appears:

```
print("type in your addition problem with your x variable first. (x variable = your first number) CAUTION: This calculator only supports 2 numbers at the moment.") ; sleep(float(speed))
        x = int(input())
        print("Type in your y variable.") ; sleep(float(speed))
        y = int(input())
        mathResult = x + y
        print(x + "+" + y + "=" + mathResult + ".") ; sleep(float(speed))
```

Comment: The error message seems quite clear; you could stop trying to add integers to strings.

Comment: You can use `print(x, '+', y, .....)` if you're OK with having spaces between the values and symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python3: `print(x , "+" , y , "=" , mathResult , ".")`

Answer (score 1):

Just try putting commas instead of `+`:

```
print x , "+" , y , "=" , mathResult , "."
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on python 3.6.

```py
print(f"{x} + {y} = {mathResult}.")
```